# Apache: Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtualhost

I am working on my old windows 7 user for a month and everything works fine but eventually, our admin gave me new ADID (active directory ID). Then when i log on using that ADID. My localhost is not working anymore. It gives me an error below :

```
Error (dns_unresolved_hostname) 
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
For assistance, Please. contact our Help Desk.
```

I tried to navigate at http://ip_address/ and it is working fine but the `localhost` is really gives me a headache.

But when i try to log on using my old ADID. Everything is back to normal. Already tried to reinstall xampp and laragon on my new ADID. Already tried everything i saw on the internet, and still not working.

By the way, this is my hosts

```
127.0.0.1      localhost 
127.0.0.1      sample1.dev
127.0.0.1      sample2.dev
```

My configuration on my XAMPP is the default. I haven't reconfigure it yet since fresh install.

Update : While i'm investigating this case, i try to remove my internet connection then navigate to `http://localhost`. My browser says "No internet connection" so in my understanding, my `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` is pointing outside my local machine. Any idea guys?

Comment: run `ping localhost` to know the IP also clear your dns cache

Comment: It says `Reply from ::1:time <1ms` and 100% loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [article](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot#) help me much.

All i did was to remove my proxy temporarily and run Laragon. Then after i checked that my localhost is working properly, i set up my proxy again.

Answer (score 0):

`::1` is IPv6 version for `127.0.0.1`. to resolve to localhost, try:

- edit `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and change the `Listen 80` to
  `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` or
- disable IPv6 in your adapter or
- change virtualhost to
  `<VirtualHost *:80>` or `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>`