# Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS error accessing website using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I am trying to use selenium on Windows. Whenever I run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
path = "C:/Users/User/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=path)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I get the following error. I don’t really understand the problem. I am not using a proxy or anything like that. Therefore I don't think it is related to my network but I could be completely wrong.

````
in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>```
````

Comment: How _certain_ are you that you're not using a proxy? Are you using a corporate computer or a personal one? Can you provide the traceback? Is the error happening on the last line or before that?

Comment: Do you get anything different if you use https, i.e. https:// www .python.org

Comment: @PangolinPaws No it doesn’t change anything when I use a different website.

Comment: @sytech It happens at the line: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=path,desired_capabilities=capabilities)`

Comment: @BrianHode try without passing `options` or `desired_capabilities`. Do you get the same error? I would also double-check the version of chrome you are using and that it matches your chromedriver version... another thought... `localhost` should be in your system's `hosts` file. Your browser shouldn't even be trying to do DNS lookups. Is it possible you've removed `localhost` from your `hosts` file?

Comment: @sytechMy chrome version matches my web driver, localhost is in contained my hosts file

Comment: I also tried switching my driver to Firefox but the same error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS
```

...implies that as per the **DNS** entries *localhost* wasn't resolved properly.

Ensure that *`hosts`* file have the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
```

Incase you are behind a proxy, you may like to:

- Remove the proxy settings temporarily.
- Ensure *localhost* is resolved by DNS.
- Set up the proxy again.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Apache: Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45414031/7429447)

---

### tl; dr

[hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot?](https://serverfault.com/q/452268/488038)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you verry much